# Is there way to join condition in css selector seleniuim

Tags: selenium

Is there way to join **CSS selector** condition using **OR** , **AND**

example

```
tag[attribute=somevalue1 or attribute2=somevalue2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can write like this

```
XPATH: //input[@name='login'and @type='submit']

CSS: input[name='login'][type='submit']
```

Comment: I want to know, How to join the CSS selector using "OR" ?